# With Selenium, I want to find elements by text like Ctrl-F “Find in Page” in Chrome does

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-webdriver-python

Working with Selenium I need to find an element. Contrary to what is recommended, I want to find that element based on what the user sees. I know that this is difficult to solve
in the general case, but at least I want to be able to go for elements based on what text/label they carry.

In my case I have an `<input type=submit value=text_I_see>`, but it might also be a `<button>`, a normal link or even a not so normal link (e.g. JavaScript onclick-thingy) etc.

**The browser’s <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> “Find in page...” search box finds what I want. It highlights it perfectly. And I want to click exactly that!** How do I do this?

I **do not** want to find it using:

- id
- class
- element/tag name
- element specifics
- information only seen in the HTML source

Is this standard use case not supported at all?

Comment: `driver.find_elements(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "your text here")`

Comment: @JohnGordon this may be not a link, just a text inside element